# What is the benefit of using late keyword for non-nullable variable?

Tags: dart

One of the benefits I saw is (from [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety#creating-variables))

> The runtime lazily initializes the late variable. For example, if a non-nullable instance variable must be calculated, adding the late modifier delays the calculation until the first use of the instance variable.

But when I try to implement this in code:

```
late int realInt;

void main() {
  calculate();
  print(realInt);
}

void calculate() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => realInt = 1);
```

It gives me an error

> Error: LateInitializationError: Field 'realInt' has not been initialized.

So, what's the meaning of that line mentioned in docs if the process of delaying isn't working on its own?

Comment: I don't care about making the code work by using `async-await`, I just want to know how `late` keyword benefits as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: See https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at the following example:

```
void main() {
  final a = A(5);
  
  print('Before fetching realInt');
  print(a.realInt);
  print('After fetching realInt');
  print(a.realInt);
  print('After another fetching realInt');
}

class A {
  final int value;
  late int realInt = calculate();

  A(this.value);
  
  int calculate() {
    print('Some hard work...');
    return value*value;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Before fetching realInt
Some hard work...
25
After fetching realInt
25
After another fetching realInt
```

As you can see, the `late` keyword here is more used like a lazy evaluated value which will first be calculated at the first usage. This is equal to the behavior we have today with static variables (which are also lazy evaluated) but with `late` we can now do the same for class member variables.

`late` can also be used to indicate that the variable is going to be initialized before use which is what you have done in your example. But because of how asynchronously code are working, you are ending up trying to fetch the value before it has been set to any value which will throw an `Exception`.

`late` can therefore not be used as an alternative to `Future`.

Comment: So basically it's just like a `static` variable since the value can be assigned to it just once but unlike `static` it can be given a value at some later point in the future. Right? Docs don't mention anything like that.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization and https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables